# Create HTML and JS widgets an integrate them to native and hybrid apps

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, widget

first of all, thanks for reading my question. I have a new challenge at work, build some HTML and JS widgets to integrate them in Native and Hybrid mobile apps. My questions are:

1. How native and hybrid mobile apps can embed JS widgets in their user interface?
2. Suppose we have a basic form widget already inside the app, how the widget sends back some extra data to the application?

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking, your form will be connected via "control" or "model" to some type of storage, either locally in the browser, or a remote database.

Hybrid apps written in JS use a "Web View" to render HTML without browser chrome (ie. no URL bar). Here is Apple's [UIWebView Class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) and here is the [Android WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView)

I recommend you take a look at some popular JS frameworks for hybrid/native app development to determine whether any of them meet your technical requirements. A more specific answer to your questions will differ depending on the framework you choose.

Below are links to see how forms work using three popular JS libraries, but these are not your only options.

1. [React Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)
2. [Ionic Forms](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/forms/)
3. [Vue forms](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

fwiw, [React](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) and [Vue](https://vue-native.io/) each have a specific library for native app development, but Ionic uses the same library for both native and hybrid mobile development.

To understand widgets, look up components or elements in the documentation for the framework you choose. Generally speaking, once you create a functioning widget, you can insert it directly into your HTML-based template and inject it with whatever data you need in order to render any dynamic elements.